# Ms Project 2007 - How to put duration of task as 1 day and keeping the end date the same

Tags: microsoft-project

I have found many articles on this but none have seem to help me.

I want to put duration of a task for one day and I want the start date and end date to be the same.

My logic is as its one day it should be the same.

I have tried work time and many other options but nothing seems to work.

Please help.

Comment: You mean, you want to change the duration of a task to hours instead of days?

Comment: I mean I want to put 1 day and then the start date and end date should be the same day . I don't know why it goes to the next day

Comment: any one ? pls help

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly because there is a mismatch between the number of hours you have declared to be "in a day" (probably left as the default 8) and the number of hours you are actually working in a day (probably defined in the Working Time as 7 or 7.5).

Firstly set your working hours properly. Then set the "duration" of a day to equalt the number of hours worked in a day according to what you have set in the Working Time.

Unfortunately you will have to go through all tasks and reset their durations as fiddling with the above will have recalculated the durations of all tasks.

This is a common mistake with MSP and the way around it is to ALWAYS set up your working calendars and working times when you set up a new project and definitely BEFORE adding any tasks...

Answer (score 0):

When I face this, I try changing the Date format (In MS Project 2010, it's File > Options > General > Date Format) to something like "Jan 28, 12:33 PM"

Then sometimes I notice that the tasks is starting at 10:00 and a full 8 hour (or 1 day) task ends up during the beginning of the next day. Then I change my start to 9:00 AM of that day (assuming the default is set at 9 to 5) and the task finishes at 5:00 PM the same day.

Not sure if this is the reason, but something you can try out.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the tasks start time is still the default time instead of the time you had set. Thus when your working day hours are longer than the standard 8 hours, part of the work spills over to the next day. I changed the tasks' starting time constraint in task information to "as soon as possible" and this solved the problem for me.